# Calculate $\iint_R \cos\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\text{d}A$

Tags: integration, analysis, substitution

Hello I would like to know if I answered the question correctly,

> Calculate $\iint_R \cos\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\text{d}A$ with $R$ the region under the graph of $y = x^3$, between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$.

I calculated the following integral with substitution at first with $u = g(y)= \frac{y}{x} = \frac{1}{x}y$, that gives $\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}y} = \frac{1}{x}$. In the sixth equation I used partial integration $f(x)g'(x)\text{d}x = f(x)g(x) - \int g(x)f'(x) \text{d}x$ with $f(x) = x, f'(x) = 1, g'(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = -\cos(x)$.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_0^{x^3} \cos \left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \text{d}y\text{d}x 
&= \int_0^1\int_{g(0)}^{g(x^3)} \cos(u) x\text{d}u\text{d}x \\
&=\int_0^1x\int_{\frac{0}{x}}^{\frac{x^3}{x}} \cos(u) \text{d}u\text{d}x\\
&= \int_0^1x\cdot \left[\sin(u)\right]_0^{x^2} \text{d}x\\
&= \int_0^1x\cdot \left[\sin(\frac{y}{x})\right]_0^{x^2} \text{d}x\\
&= \int_0^1 x \sin(x) \text{d}x \\
& = \left[x(-\cos(x)) - \int -\cos(x) \text{d}x \right]_0^1 \\
&= \left[-x \cos(x) +\sin(x)\right]_0^1 \\
&= -1\cos(1)+\sin(1) - \left(-0 \cos(0) + \sin(0)\right) \\
&= -\cos(1) + \sin(1).
\end{align*}

Comment: Question is confusing.  Under the curve - how far?  What us y in $cos(\frac{y}{x})$?

Comment: It only says between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. $y$ is just the $y$-coordinate

Comment: You have an error - should be $sin(x^3)$.

Comment: Looks correct, except the second expression should be $\int_0^1 \int_0^{x^2} \cos(u) x\, du\, dx$. But apparently you had the correct version somewhere, since you then have the correct $\sin(x^2)$ at the next step.

Comment: @aschepler I believe my $\sin(x^2)$ becomes $\sin(x)$ then as when i fill in the bounds $x^2$ and $0$ in $\sin(u) = \sin(\frac{y}{x})$ then this will be $\sin(\frac{x^2}{x}) = \sin(x)$ right?

Comment: Do *not* do substitutions in multiple integrals without using the full change of variables theorem. You can do a substitution off on the side to evaluate an antiderivative, but don’t tamper with the iterated integrals.

Comment: your computation is wrong, when you evaluate between $0$ and $x^2$ you can't go back to $y/x$ as you've changed the bounds. You've to evaluate $\sin u$ for $u=x^2$ and $u=0$

Comment: The upper limit of the inner integral is $y=x^3$ or $u=x^2$, but not $y=x^2$. We don't usually write integrals this way, but think of them as $$\int_{y=0}^{y=x^3} \cos \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\, dy = \int_{u=0}^{u=x^2} \cos(u)\, x\, du$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use a substitution and worry about new bounds of integration:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{x^3} \cos \left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \text{d}y\text{d}x =\int_0^1\int_0^{x^3}\frac{x}{x} \cos \left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \text{d}y\text{d}x=\int_0^1 x\left[\sin \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right]_{y=0}^{y=x^3}\text{d}x= \\
=\int_0^1 x \sin (x^2)\text{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}\cos x^2 \bigg \vert_0^1 =\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos 1 \right) $$

Comment: I believe the bounds have to change I have edited my post

Comment: @Willem I'll take a look in a while, but my computation is still correct

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your calculation is mostly correct, but after the first substitution, you should have $x^2$ as upper bound and not $x^3$.

However, you should maybe state more clearly that $R$ is the area bounded by the graphs $y=x^3$ *and* $y=0$ in between $x=0$ and $x=1$. Else, it is not clear what the lower $y$-bound of the domain is.

Comment: Thanks! Where should I have $x^2$ as upper bound? I don't understand

Comment: When using substitution, you also have to change the bounds on the integral. So when you change $\frac{y}{x}$ to $u$, the upper bound must change from $x^3$ to $x^2$.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that! How do you know it changes to $x^2$?

Comment: Lets say your substitution function is a differentiable bijection $\phi : [a,b]\rightarrow [\phi(a),\phi(b)]$ between two intervals, and $f:[\phi(a),\phi(b)]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $$\int\limits_a^b f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)d t = \int\limits_{\phi(a)}^{\phi(b)} f(s)d s.$$

Comment: I changed the post with the change of variable theorem in it